# Find TypeOf Child class when casted as Parent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Partial View that I want be able to use with several different models. Is there any way to find out what the Child class of an object is when it is being passed in as its parent?

For example:

Model:

```
public class Animal { }
public class Dog : Animal { }
public class Cat : Animal { }
```

Controller:

```
public class AnimalActionController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MakeAnimalSound(Animal animal)
    {
       if (animal is Dog)
       {
         return PartialView("~/Views/_AnimalActionView.cshtml", new{sound="Woof"});
       }
       if (animal is Cat)
       {
         return PartialView("~/Views/_AnimalActionView.cshtml", new{sound="Meow"});
       }
    }
}
```

Parent View of Dog page:

```
@model Test.Models.Dog
@Html.Action("MakeAnimalSound", "AnimalAction", new { Model })
```

Right now if I were to do something like this example the if statements in the Controller only see animal as Animal and not as Dog or Cat which it originally was.

Anyone know how to do this? I feel like it should be simple.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean if you pass in a `Dog` object, the `if` condition `if (animal is Dog)` evaluates as `false`?

Comment: Unless you have a changed the default `ModelBinder` you will always get an `Animal` and never a `Dog` or `Cat`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair, Yes, when I pass in dog the if statement returns false. I want it to return true because the origin of the model that was passed is Dog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better choice for this would be to do something like this.  Testing class types is a poor design and considered a code smell in most cases (sometimes it's necessary, but there's usually other ways to accomplish what you want without it):

```
public class Animal
{
     public virtual Sound {get;}
}
public class Dog : Animal
{
     public override Sound {get {return "Woof";}}
}
public class Cat : Animal
{
     public override Sound {get {return "Meow";}}
}

public ActionResult MakeAnimalSound(Animal animal)
{
   return PartialView("~/Views/_AnimalActionView.cshtml", new{sound=animal.Sound});
}
```

Comment: The default ModelBinder will always pass an `Animal` into the method, never a `Dog` or `Cat`, by design.

Comment: @ErikPhilips - I don't think that applies to child actions because you're passing the model directly to it, and it's not being model bound.

Comment: Hmm, then why not just pass the Animal directly in instead of an anonymous object?  Seems to be it would be better to have a strongly typed View of the actual model.  I'd also recommend decorating the method with [ChildActionOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) to reduce the security exposure.

Comment: This does propose a possible alternate solution, but the OP's question was "Is there any way to find out what the Child class of an object is when it is being passed in as its parent?"

Comment: @Steve - And I said doing that is a poor design, so I addressed the question.. basically it's "You shouldn't"

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've gone ahead and just made different ActionResults in the controller to handle each class that will be passed into it. I'm making a web game and wanted to have a partial view to control Build Queue, but the build queue can be accessed from a Fleet view or a Planet view, etc. I then want to see if its being accessed by a Fleet I can pull properties from the fleet to see what should be displayed (ie. a fleet cant build a fighter ship w/o having a hanger or something, likewise a planet cant build a fighter w/o a starport). I will scrap that method though.

Answer (score 2):

If you call the object's GetType() method, you will get an object that will tell you everything you need to know. See [the MSDN page on System.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx).

The following program outputs `Child`.

```
internal class Parent {
    private string Something { get; set; }
}

internal class Child : Parent {
    private int SomethingElse { get; set; }
}

internal class Program {

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Parent reallyChild = new Child();
        Console.WriteLine(reallyChild.GetType().Name);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know about that method. This does not work in my case though since the model is being passed into the controller as the parent the GetType().Name is saying that it is the parent still.